# Split strings in JavaScript with special delimiter

Tags: javascript, java, string, split, ascii

I create a String in server side (with java) including special characters like (char)007 and I want to split the String with this delimiter in client side with JavaScript.
The reason to use this character is, it can not be input from keyboard.
Is it possible to split a String in JavaScript with character like (char)007?
How to specify the character in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

- Use the `\uXXXX` form to specify the symbol in the string literal:

  ```
  str.split("\u0007")
  ```
- Convert a `char 7` to a String:

  ```
  str.split(Character.toString((char) 7));
  ```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Cor1xB)